# JavaScript hover menu not disappearing when it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

Alright, so I'm trying to write a drop-down menu in JavaScript, but it doesn't vanish when it should (on mouse out). How do I make it vanish when it should?

Here is the site it's on: http://prime.programming-designs.com/designs/graymech/about.htm

Comment: I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it into beta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have ReferenceError on lines 31 and 43 in your code where a function called `IsMouseOver` is invoked.

Appears as though this function doesn't exist in your code.